Cloned Fineract from Apache but had Gradle issues with AsciidoctorPDF, OAuth, and two-factor auth

Task :fineract-doc:asciidoc

1: Task failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':fineract-doc:asciidoctorPdf'.


Remote Asciidoctor process failed to complete successfully


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
I checked the plugins and dependencies of the asciiDoctorPDF but couldn't find what was wrong. How should I resolve it? and if the gradle is built successfully how should I proceed forward to install fineract?
